# Control of boundary integral via the whole domain integral

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ is a bounded domain and $K \Subset \Omega$ such that $\partial K \in C^m$ for some $m$ large. Then for $f \geq 0$ and $f \in C(\overline{\Omega})$, can we write this:

$$\int_{\partial K} f ~dS \leq C \int_{\Omega} f ~dx$$

for some $C>0$ independent of $f.$

Comment: No. Consider a nonnegative function $f$ that is $=1$ on $\partial K$. Then $\int_\Omega f$ can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: How can you make $\int_{\Omega} f$ small? By continuity, we may choose $K_1 \subset K$ of non-zero measure close to $K$ so that the values of function $f$ belongs to $(1-\epsilon, 1)$.